# Sublists of consecutive similar elements from a list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, grouping

I'm new to Prolog and trying to do this question. We have a list

```
List = [a,a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a,d,e,e,e,e]
```

I want to pack it into sub-lists of similar elements.

```
Pack( [a,a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a,d,e,e,e,e], Sublists)
```

should give

```
Sublists = [[a,a,a,a],[b],[c,c],[a,a],[d],[e,e,e,e]]
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
pack([],[],[]).
pack([H],[H],[H]).
pack([H,H1|T],Z,X):- H==H1 , append([H],Z,Z1) , pack([H1|T],Z1,X).
pack([H,H1|T],Z,X):- H=\=H1 , append([H],Z,Z1) , 
                              append(Z1,X,Xs) , pack([H1|T],Z1,Xs).
```

Below is the error:

> ```
>   Arithmetic: `a/0' is not a function
>
>   In:
>      [4] a=\=b
>      [3] pack([a,b|...],[a,a],_1608) at  line 13
>      [2] pack([a,a|...],[a],_1688) at  line 13
>      [1] pack([a,a|...],[],_1762) at  line 13
> ```

Thanks in advance. I'm trying to solve these problems:

- [P-99: Ninety-Nine Prolog Problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/).

Answer (score 4):

You can approach this kind of problem with simple list processing and using SWI Prolog's `dif/2` to provide a general solution:

```
pack([], []).       % packing empty is empty
pack([X], [[X]]).   % packing a single element
pack([X,X|T], [[X|PH]|PT]):- % rule for packing when next two terms are the same
    pack([X|T], [PH|PT]).
pack([X,Y|T], [[X]|PT]):-    % rule for different term
    dif(X, Y),
    pack([Y|T], PT).

2 ?- pack([a,a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a,d,e,e], L).
L = [[a, a, a, a], [b], [c, c], [a, a], [d], [e, e]] ;
false.

3 ?- pack(L, [[a,a,a], [b,b], [c]]).
L = [a, a, a, b, b, c] ;
false.

4 ?-
```

Comment: @Ch3steR your answer helped the Op understand the difference between `=\=/2` and `\=/2`, so that's a good thing!

Comment: @Ch3steR I've done that myself numerous times. I usually like to help the OP understand why their solution didn't work, and that's what your answer did. I posted a different answer as an alternative solution, but didn't go into the failure of the original post since you had already covered that. :) Sometimes a posted question has other more critical issues with their code that requires an answer that deviates completely from the original.

Comment: @lurker I've learnt something new today in Prolog thanks to you. :')

Answer (score 3):

Note that [lurker's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59456699/772868) still has some performance issues. See the `; false` for each solution? This is an indication that Prolog still retains some memory (called a choice point - actually there may be even several such choice points).  For many cases however, no such choice point is needed.  Here is a solution that overcomes that problem (The name `group` in place of `pack` is quite common in the context of Haskell)

```
group([], []).
group([E|Es], [[E|Gs]|Gss]) :-
   igroup(Es, E, Gs, Gss).

igroup([], _, [], []).
igroup([E|Es], F, Gs1, Gss1) :-
    (   E\=F
    ->  Gs1=[], Gss1=[[E|Gs2]|Gss2]
    ;   E==F
    ->  Gs1=[E|Gs2], Gss1=Gss2
    ;   E=F,
        Gs1=[E|Gs2], Gss1=Gss2
    ;   dif(E, F),
        Gs1=[], Gss1=[[E|Gs2]|Gss2]
    ),
    igroup(Es, E, Gs2, Gss2).
```

Note how the testing for the equality of `E` and `F` is split into four cases:

1. First `E \= F` which means that both are definitely different.
2. Then `E == F` which means that both are definitely identical.
3. Then `E = F` which is the general case of equality, and
4. `dif(E, F)` which is the case of general inequality

For the last two cases there is no `->` because both may be true.
Since it is quite cumbersome to maintain so many cases, there is  `library(reif)`
for
[SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl) and
[SWI](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl) which permits to write the same more compactly:

```
igroup([], _, [], []).
igroup([E|Es], F, Gs1, Gss1) :-
   if_(E = F
      , ( Gs1 = [E|Gs2], Gss1 = Gss2 )
      , ( Gs1 = [], Gss1 = [[E|Gs2]| Gss2] )),
   igroup(Es, E, Gs2, Gss2).
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you got is because `=\=/2` is true if `expr1` is evaluates to a *number* not equal to `expr2` . Instead you can use `\=\2` which evaluates `\+term1=term2`. `==/2` evaluates to `term1 equivalent to term2`,  `=:=/` is true if `expr1` is a *number* which is *equal* to `expr2`. One more mistake I found in your code is you're not clearing the Intermediate List. You have to flush the values in it after you have added the similar elements list to your `Sublists` list. I have used cut `!` to reduce backtracking. Instead, if you write mutually exclusive predicates, it's better.

I have edited your code:

```
pack1([],[],[]).
pack1([H],L,[Z]):- append([H],L,Z),!.
pack1([H,H1|T],Z,X):- H == H1 , append([H],Z,Z1) , pack1([H1|T],Z1,X),!.
pack1([H,H1|T],Z,[Z1|Zs]):- H\=H1 ,append([H],Z,Z1) ,pack1([H1|T],[],Zs),!.
```

**Output:**

```
?-pack1([a,a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a,d,e,e,e,e],[],Z).
  Z=[[a, a, a, a], [b], [c, c], [a, a], [d], [e, e, e, e]]
?-pack1([a,a,a,a,b,c,1,c,a,a,d,e,e,e,e],[],Z).
  Z= [[a, a, a, a], [b], [c], [1], [c], [a, a], [d], [e, e, e, e]]
?-pack1([],[],Z).
  Z= []
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man. It works. I'm new to prolog didnot understand what cut is.

Comment: You explore more about `cut` here. http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/dictionaries/prolog/cut.html

Comment: It would be a good exercise to try to solve this without the cut. The cut is often overused, as in this case. It loses generality at the expense of getting a short term solution to a logic problem.

Comment: @lurker I used `cut` so that `false` that comes after will be eliminated. I was told by someone in SO that you should try to eliminate the `false` that comes after the answer.

Comment: @Ch3ster, yes, the extra `false` is due to a remaining choice point. The solution can be correct in that case, but it means the solution isn't completely deterministic (not wrong though). A cut is used often as a short-cut to fix it, but the cut eliminates the generality of the solution. In this case, since there's always only one solution either way, it can work.

Comment: Yes, got your point.Your solution is more accurate than mine. My solution would fail for queries like this `pack1(Z,[],[[a, a, a, a], [b], [c, c], [a, a], [d], [e, e, e, e]]).`

Comment: @Ch3steR I did discover if I put a cut after `pack([X|T], [PH|PT])` in the solution I posted I can get rid of the "false" in both of my examples, but I'm still not sure I want to do it since I haven't tried more query examples. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204738/discussion-between-ch3ster-and-lurker).

Answer (score 0):

without using `dif/2`

```
my_pack([],[[]]).
my_pack([X], [[X]]).
my_pack([X,X|L], [F|R]) :- my_pack([X|L], [F1|R]), append([X], F1, F).
my_pack([X|L], [F|R]) :-  my_pack(L, R), append([X], [], F).
```